# How to return string from activity started for result

Tags: android

I have started Activity for result, but how to return string like parameter from that activity ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

just use following code block:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.putExtra("RESULT_STRING", string);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

get value from this intent in onActivtyResult method in calling activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == CREATE_REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Use Data to get string
        String string = data.getStringExtra("RESULT_STRING");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `putExtra` in the `intent` and the call `setResult()`,

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("myobj", value);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) says it all. You set the result by calling setResult and you read it in the onActivityResult method.