# Firebase phone authentication is working fine in debug mode but the app is crashing in release

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-permissions

Is it because of permissions?

I have granted `READ_SMS , RECEIVE_SMS, READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions at the run-time but still its crashing.

```
12-26 10:56:02.409 30698-30698/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=55, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.app.eco4ndly.pathshala/com.app.eco4ndly.pathshala.Opening_Screen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4255)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4298)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                      at com.app.eco4ndly.pathshala.Opening_Screen.onActivityResult(Opening_Screen.java:108)
                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6948)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4251)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4298) 
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613) 
                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339) 
                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
```

What else needed to be done?

**UPDATE**

in **Openning_Screen.java**

```
private void attemptsRegistration() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Opening_Screen.this,PhoneVerification.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constant.REQUEST_CODE,55);
    startActivityForResult(intent,55);
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        final View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        if (requestCode == 55){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            if (result.equals("PhoneVerifiedSuccessfully")){
                RegistrationDataPass.setPhone(data.getStringExtra("phone"));
                Intent i = new Intent(Opening_Screen.this,RegPage1.class);
                i.putExtra("PhoneNumber",data.getStringExtra("phone"));
                startActivity(i);
            }else if (result.equals("InvalidCode")){
                Constant.showSnak(view,"Registration Failed\nInvalid Code");
            }else if (result.equals("INVALID REQUEST")){
                Constant.showSnak(view,"Registration Failed\nINVALID REQUEST");
            }else if (result.equals("Too many Request")){
                Constant.showSnak(view,"Registration Failed\nToo many Requests");
            }
        }
}
```

`Phone_Verification.java` code is huge I'm explaining how it works.
When it starts I'm checking for permissions for **marshmallow** then after all permissions are granted the phone number is taken as input from user and then its going to `verifyPhone()`

```
public void verifyPhone(String phn, PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks _mCallbacks){
    mCallbacksResend = _mCallbacks;
    Constant.showProgressBar(this,"You will receive an OTP in "+phn);
    Log.e("STEP Inside ver pn",phn);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phn,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            _mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallback
}
```

And the verification call back is like this

```
final PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallBacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("JEJE", "onVerificationCompleted:" + phoneAuthCredential);
            Log.e("STEP in signin","InsideVerification");
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Constant.hideProgressBar();
            Log.w("JEJE", "onVerificationFailed", e);
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                Log.d("JEJE", "INVALID REQUEST");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("result","INVALID REQUEST");
                intent.putExtra("phone",phoneNumber);
                setResult(REQ_CODE,intent);
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Log.d("JEJE", "Too many Request");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("result","Too many Request");
                intent.putExtra("phone",phoneNumber);
                setResult(REQ_CODE,intent);
            }
            showSnakBar(e.toString());
            //hideProgressDialog();
            Constant.hideProgressBar();
            Toast.makeText(PhoneVerification.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            //hideProgressDialog();
            Constant.hideProgressBar();
            Log.d("JEJE", "onCodeSent:" + s);
            mResendToken = forceResendingToken;
            tv.setText("We have sent a verification Code to your number "+phoneNumber+" via SMS.\nEnter the CODE bellow");
            phoneNumLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            otpLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            verifyToken = s;
            showTimer();
        }
    };
```

The app is crashing after showing the the progress bar in `verifyPhone()`. No code is being sent.

Comment: share related code

Comment: Are you sure this error is version-related?

Comment: It is `NullPointerException` . post your `Opening_Screen.java` file.

Comment: @Nilu no it's not. Fortunately, I know what NullPointerException is.

Comment: @Dharmishtha here is the code in the **update** .

Comment: @Xenolion ya you were right. This error was not for the version. I got this in a wrong way

Comment: I am glad you solved it **Happy Coding!** and Congratulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, **the problem has been solved**.

My understanding of the problem was wrong. The problem was not because of the Android version. The problem arose for every version.

**Reason**

As I described that the application was working fine in debug mode but not working in release mode. I used firebase phone authentication. And there `SHA certificate fingerprints` are needed. Unfortunately, I forgot to provide release SHA-1. I was using debug SHA-1 fingerprint for the release version.

**Solution**

Provided the release SHA-1 fingerprint.

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem @Sayann congratulation and thanks for the answer!!

Comment: Hi, how to get release SHA-1 fingerprint

Comment: you can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933380/sha1-key-for-debug-release-android-studio-mac

Comment: Do we again need to update the google-services.json and roll out a new version of the app?

Answer (score 0):

IMO you have to pass proper `key,value` pair to `intent.puExtra()` try below code

```
intent.putExtra("result",55);
```

then your `data.getStringExtra("result");` get value

```
 if (requestCode == 55){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
```

**OR** try below code this may help

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Opening_Screen.this,PhoneVerification.class);
intent.putExtra(Constant.REQUEST_CODE,55);
intent.putExtra("result",YOUR_RESULT_STRING);
intent.putExtra("phone",PHONE_STRING);
startActivityForResult(intent,55);
```

for more check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225961/6834114)

Comment: I think this is not the problem.My codes are working perfectly fine in debug mode.Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @SayannPoria share line no :108 at Opening_Screen.java

Comment: `String result = data.getStringExtra("result");`

Answer (score 0):

after adding @Omi's answer , here is another one condition which you need to put .

```
if (requestCode == 55 && data!=null){
  //here your code
}
```

Hope this Help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **settings-> developer options -> Application** section &
Make sure your 'Do Not keep activities' option is off then try